# Multiple SQL SP Questions

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

Okay, I have multiple questions concerning two of my `SQL Stored procedures`.
1 - I have about 10 different commands in my stored procedure that all do the same thing but give me different results. It's for a game. It's basically a class change. What I want to do is - I want to put them together into one big `command/script` instead of having 10 different ones, but every time I try doing something like :

```
`if(@ActionType = 114 AND @Value2 > 44141 AND @Value2 < 44148)
SET @DP =(
CASE 
 WHEN @Value2 = 44142 THEN 25
 WHEN @Value2 = 44143 THEN 50
 WHEN @Value2 = 44144 THEN 75
 WHEN @Value2 = 44145 THEN 100
 WHEN @Value2 = 44146 THEN 1000
 WHEN @Value2 = 44147 THEN 10000
ELSE @DP
END)`
```

I got an error. ( That's another command on the same SP ) 
One example of my 10 commands is -

```
IF( @ActionType = 112 ) 
  BEGIN 
      IF( @Value2 = 100194 ) 
        BEGIN 
    Exec dbo.usp_ICC  @CharID
            UPDATE PS_GameData.dbo.Chars
            SET    Family = 0, Job = 0 
            WHERE  CharID = @CharID 
END 
  END
```

Also, I am making it to the point where I'm trying to execute that `dbo.usp_ICC @CharID  Procedure`, but it doesn't execute it even though it should. I get no changes / responses whenever it supposedly executes it. I'm not sure what could be wrong?

P.S. Both, the `Stored Procedure` that has the previously shown codes and the stored procedure that is trying to get executed are both in the same database.

Comment: Hello Carlos, first thing I saw, `IF [condition] THEN [statements] [...] END IF`

Comment: And a humble tip, if SQL is not object oriented, at least you can continue thinking object oriented

Comment: This looks suspiciously like SQL-Server syntax, but the question has a MySQL tag, can you clarify which DBMS you are using?

Comment: I'm using SQL Management Studio Express 2005